# Jenkins Test Result Management

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, build-process

I'm working with a Jenkins system, and I've recently started working to optimize the tests. There are almost a thousand Selenium tests and twice as many unit and integration tests.

I'm wondering if there is some way to find which tests are the most prone to failure so we can attack the worst offenders first. It would also be nice if there was an integrated way to track who is working on which test, and if a test has been fixed, what was done to fix it. I'm new to Jenkins, so please point me to some documentation or a plugin I can install that would help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing is [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)  which can tie SCMs to issues to releases to developers.

There is [Jenkins to JIRA integration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) to create Jira issues out of Jenkins